# Highcharts doesn't resize properly once expanded

Tags: highcharts

For some reason once you expand the window the chart doesn't resize down properly.  You should still be able to see the red spacer.

I made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bryaan/pjyzxbdu/10/

```
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

.table-row {
  display: flex;
  margin 10px;
}
.table-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve two equal boxes sets `display:flex` to parent and add children `width: 50%`.

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
#container {
  width: 50%;
}
.spacer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/46o7venk/